# Nueva funcionalidad para copiar «código fuente» al portapapeles

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

### Nueva funcionalidad para copiar «código fuente» al portapapeles

Me gustaría que pudisese implementarse en **Stack Overflow** una función que permita copiar al **portapapeles** los fragmentos de *código* publicados en las preguntas y/o respuestas. Es decir, que en lugar de realizarse en una PC, Tablet_ o Smartphone_ de una forma parecida a esto:

[image: Vista Previa]

Simplemente se presione *un botón* para permitir realizar la misma acción antes descrita. Es decir, algo parecido al siguiente ejemplo:

[image: Vista Previa]

Entonces, mi motivación respecto a este tema es facilitarle el trabajo a las personas (incluyéndome) que realicen preguntas y respuestas para copiar el código de forma segura y probarlos *in situ* de forma rápida, además de, reducir los famosos *errores humanos*, que es cuando seleccionamos fragmentos de código, sobre todo, si son demasiados largos.

#### Estas serían las interrogantes para una posible propuesta:

- ¿Qué posibilidades existen o a quién(es) habría que dirigirse para proponer la implementación de la función antes descrita?
- Y en el caso de que no sea posible, ¿cuál sería la posible razón?
- Y por último, tomando en cuenta todo lo planteado, ¿estarían de acuerdo de que se implementara dicha caractarística nueva a **Stack Overflow**?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Interesante y útil propuesta.

Comment: Mientras tanto, hay una interesante extensión para chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-code/ophfcfplhjmiakmfeemkpaoofhjlmkof

Comment: Gracias Patricio por la información. Es muy intereante. Sin embargo, me surge otra interrogante, ¿es posible hacer lo mismo en una _Tablet_ o _Smartphone_?

Comment: No lo sé, si sé que se pueden instalar eventualmente algunas extensiones de chrome desktop en la versión móvil, pero habría que probarlo.

Comment: EStas cosas se plantean en el sitio para toda la red, [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Es una propuesta super interesante. Sin animo de ser negativo, ten en cuenta que muchas veces esta clase de pedidos ni siquiera recibe respuestas, pero te aliento a que lo intentes!

Comment: @gbianchi, considero que no has sido negativo para nada. Por el contrario, estás suministrando información útil sobre dónde publicarlo al igual que lo ha hecho Patricio Moracho sobre el tema de las extensiones, aunque todavía me falta entender un poco mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. De hecho, me parece interesante tu observación. Lo que me quedaría es saber si puedo publicar esta misma interrogante en Stack Exchange sin que sea duplicado o realizar un planteamiento de forma similar.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Encontré que la pregunta estaba hecha hace 10 años. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow

Comment: Por un momento pensé que esta publicación era un anuncio, no una propuesta. Así que tuve un orgasmito y después una decepciónaza.

Comment: Ya agregaron la función de copiar código en Stack Overflow en Inglés. [Miren este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158718/unable-to-show-formatted-html-in-tooltip). No sé desde cuándo la implementaron. Falta la implementación acá ahora.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. No me aparece la opción de copiar. ¿Podrías agregar una captura de pantalla? Quizás tengas instalada alguna extensión si es que no estás desde el celular.

Comment: Prueba dar un toque sobre el código fuente para ver si te aparece. Por ahora, está disponible en la versión en Inglés.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM.  Para que me lleguen los mensajes, así como para cualquiera, siempre se debe indicar el arroba @ junto con el nombre de usuario. En este caso no me llegó, pero vi la pregunta por casualidad. Acabo de volver a probar a ver si copiaba pero no pasa nada ¿Estás desde un Android? ¿Podrías subir capturas de pantalla sobre eso?

Comment: @ArtEze voy a realizar las pruebas. Estuve ausente porque estaba haciendo una actividad. También tengo listo una publicación sobre cómo hacer un indicador de carga. Está bastante completo, pero la voy a responder para compartirla con todos ustedes. Es muy interesante.

Comment: @ArtEze, te avisaré cuando realice las pruebas.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Perfecto, ¿Qué es un indicador de carga? ¿Es relacionado a lo de copiar o sobre otra cosa? Con respecto a lo de copiar, si estás en Android, como no se permiten extensiones, entonces no hay que hacer nada, pero si estás en Windows debes verificar que no esté instalada ninguna extensión como Tampermonkey, o alguna otra que pueda alterar el resultado del HTML.

Comment: @ArtEze, lamentablemente no está disponible para Android la función de copiar. Solamente para PC. Deberían habilitarla para cualquier dispositivo.

Comment: En cuanto al indicador de carga me refiero [a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329419/loader-en-html-y-css). Ya tengo resuelto el problema. Por ahora, estoy explicando cómo se hace la animación. He tratado de ser lo más breve posible. Aún no he publicado mi respuesta, pero ya la tengo.

Comment: @ArtEze Lo comparto no solamente para el OP, para todos que quieran utilizarlo en sus proyectos.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Recuerdo esa pregunta, le dejé un comentario pidiendo explicaciones de qué es lo que quiere lograr, porque en verdad la pregunta no se entiende. Si entendiste lo que quiso lograr y lograste resolverlo me parecería genial que pongas la respuesta.

Comment: @ArtEze a eso voy. Hasta donde entendí el OP quiere saber realizar una animación de carga similar a la animación de carga de *Google*. Estoy afinando algunos detalles. Es posible que en una hora ya lo publique.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104734/discussion-between-david-e-luna-m-and-arteze).