# ¡Activemos una nueva página para formular preguntas!

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

Hubo dos iniciativas interesantes en Stack Overflow en inglés el año pasado. La primera es el [Asistente de preguntas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/22/impact-of-ask-question-wizard/). El objetivo de la iniciativa era ayudar a una persona que hace una pregunta a navegar y guiar rápidamente sobre cómo mejorar la publicación resultante. Mirando los resultados de la iniciativa entendimos que necesitamos pensar en algunos cambios en la página Formular una pregunta. Decidimos [hacer una investigación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) (la segunda iniciativa)! Las principales preguntas de la investigación fueron:

- ¿Cuál es la experiencia de la gente al hacer una pregunta en Stack Overflow?
- ¿Qué información necesitan los usuarios antes de hacer una pregunta en Stack Overflow?
- ¿Cómo encaja Stack Overflow en los flujos de trabajo de resolución de problemas de la gente?

Los investigadores miraron los datos, realizaron entrevistas 1:1. Se prestó atención a los indicadores cuantitativos y cualitativos. Hablaron tanto con usuarios de alta reputación como con casi acechadores...

#### Resultado: una nueva página de preguntas.

[image]

La nueva página de preguntas es una unificación del asistente de preguntas y la clásica página de preguntas. De acuerdo con los datos disponibles, podemos asumir que la nueva página ayudará a hacer preguntas de buena calidad tanto a usuarios experimentados como a principiantes.

<sub>[Más sobre la investigación.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)</sub>

¿Sabes qué es lo más interesante de esta historia? La nueva página de preguntas puede ser activada en nuestro sitio!

#### ¿Qué necesitamos para activar la nueva página de preguntas?

Ahora sólo necesitamos un poco de ayuda de los usuarios: aunque la nueva página está completamente lista para ser lanzada en Stack Overflow en español, hay una cosa que nos detiene. Las traducciones. La mayoría de las cadenas de la página no están traducidas. Estoy seguro de que todos están de acuerdo en que es una idea controvertida activar una página llena de inglés en nuestro sitio.

#### ¿Cómo puede uno ayudar?

Buscamos usuarios que quieran ayudar a traducir cadenas no traducidas. Individualmente para ellos, activaremos la nueva página de preguntas por adelantado, para que puedan ver las cadenas en vivo.

Si estás dispuesto a ayudar con las traducciones, por favor envíame un correo electrónico (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) o házmelo saber en los comentarios de esta pregunta.

Lancemos juntos la nueva página, que espero que ayude a nuestros colegas a hacer sólo preguntas de alta calidad! =)

**Actualizar**

<strike>Creé un archivo csv con todas las cadenas para traducir para todos los idiomas: http://assets.rudevs.ru/extra/new_ask_question_page.csv</strike>

`<Pikoh>`En principio ya están todas las cadenas traducidas. Si alguien quiere revisar perfecto por si se nos ha escapado algo.`</Pikoh>`

Si desea ayudar, agregue sus traducciones de contribución en https://es.traducir.win

Comment: In fact, maybe activate the new ask a question page is not needed for translation. With that screen capture and traducir.win, we can translate it in virtually no time i think.(as long the strings are in transifex, of course)

Comment: Well..i have already tranlated all the strings i can see in the screen capture and that i could found in transifex. I think i would just need to see the sections _Have a non-programing question_ and _More helpful links_ expanded and we are probably good to go...In the next build you could check if i have missed any string.

Comment: @Pikoh Todas las cuerdas ya están en Transifex! Puede suceder que ya estén traducidos. Necesitamos verificar =)

Comment: Also i'd need to see the  points 2 and 3 expanded in the right top box...

Comment: @Pikoh ¿Te importa ser el que habilite la nueva página de preguntas?

Comment: Nicolas, strings -> cadenas in spanish in this context ;)

Comment: Nicolas of course. Do it and i can check that everything it's ok

Comment: @Pikoh ¡Gracias! =) Llamé a mis colegas para que activaran la función Espero que lo activen esta noche.

Comment: No problem Nicolas. Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, count on me to test this new page

Comment: I want to participate in the translation :)

Comment: Hola @NicolasChabanovsky. ¿Qué posibilidad habría para activar una función que permita copiar código? Es decir, algo parecido a esto » [Nueva funcionalidad para copiar «código fuente» al portapapeles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4558/nueva-funcionalidad-para-copiar-c%c3%b3digo-fuente-al-portapapeles).

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. ¡Hola! ¡Buena pregunta! ¿Podrías preguntarlo en MSE? La mayoría de los desarrolladores monitorean MSE para responder a tales preguntas. Como resultado, sería más rápido obtener una respuesta allí.

Comment: @Pikoh Actualicé la pregunta: agregué un enlace al archivo donde puede ver las cadenas no traducidas. ¡Gracias! =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ok, i'll take a look at them. Does that mean that i don't need my newly created account and that i can remove it?

Comment: @Pikoh Probablemente podamos guardarlo para verificar las traducciones cuando se hagan. ¿Qué piensas?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky tienes razón. Voy a mantenerlo de momento.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I think we have everything translated now (I don't know if you can double check) except some strings that I wasn't able to find (the transifex code didn't returned results in traducir): `3382adb78871663d2dff9bac66370e4c`, `3edcf768b75ea8135000dfdd0603200d`, `6e3bea41bed2a7bab634b04553740551`, `a63642b72412835e3802541217d1c2a2` (this one seems to be `ed24d0758b42bf105a0aca7ef17e7c03` now), `b8ceef748d2118f41113e94bb0198f38`, `e48044f007d334c63a8c70d1254e0ddf`, `fb769e7bf083b8e2d7b67d2052337407` and `fcc36041dffaf4591c182c2fda81c796`.

Comment: @Pikoh Es extraño, pero tampoco pude encontrar las teclas / cadenas. ¿Podría decirme qué piensa si habilitamos la página para todos y ver si podemos encontrar las cadenas?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, me gustaría plantearlo allí, aunque no hablo inglés aún. Hay una pregunta similar [hecha hace 10 años](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow) y la que [publique en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4558/nueva-funcionalidad-para-copiar-c%c3%b3digo-fuente-al-portapapeles) ¿La puedo plantear igual en MSE sin que se tome como duplicado? Me gustaría saberlo para saber si es conveniente publicarlo allí.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Creo que sería genial dejar un comentario en la publicación de MSE al menos. ¿Podría decirme si la función existe en SOen? No puedo ver el botón en mi teléfono móvil (iPhone estándar).

Comment: Si, ya vi que está disponible la función de copiar código en SOen.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, otra cosa que quería preguntar es que si en **MSE** publicarlo en español, ¿o tiene que ser únicamente en Inglés?

Comment: De todas forma, buscaré la forma de traducirla. Si existen inconsistencias en la traducción la pueden editar para mejorar la publicación. Para más tarde voy a prepararla para la publicación en **MSE**.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Yes, i'm sure we can enable the wizard for everyone. We can find easily if we forgot any string if we have more eyes to look for them. Regarding those strings, i guess that maybe they were in previous versions of the wizards and were removed later. Anyway, I asked g3rv4 to have a look at them.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. en MSE solo debe publicarse en inglés, aunque puedes agregar un enlace a tu pregunta aquí. Si tienes problemas con el inglés, tu haz la pregunta aunque sea usando un traductor online y pon el enlace por aqui y te ayudamos a mejorarla si es necesario :)

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh. Esto sería una gran ayuda. Ya me estoy montando en ello para publicarlo allí.

Comment: Listo, ya la publiqué en MSE bajo el título de «New functionality to copy code to the clipboard for "Stack Overflow" in Spanish». Es posible que tenga fallos gramaticales por la traducción, pero la pueden mejorar.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no fue bien recibida. Quedó cerrada por duplicada.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky any reason for removing the featured tag?

Comment: @Pikoh Los desarrolladores me dijeron que están listos para habilitar la función para todos los usuarios. Quiero mantener la barra lateral con solo una publicación destacada, por lo que cuando el anuncio esté en vivo, será más visible. ¿Podrías decirme qué piensas?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky that's good news. I agree, if the wizard is going to be activated and you are going to announce it in another post, that should be the featured one :)

Answer (score 6):

Ya está traducido todo (espero) lo referente al nuevo asistente de preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que el siguiente paso será activar el asistente para todo el sitio. Una vez esté disponible para todos (o ahora mismo si véis algo raro en mi traducción) podéis reportar los posibles fallos de traducción (tanto errores como cadenas que puedan haber quedado sin traducir) aquí mismo, o sugerir traducciones en [traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/).

Comment: (Google translated =) Como dijeron mis colegas, puede haber algunas cadenas para los usuarios que preguntan por primera vez. ¿Podría crear un nuevo usuario y compartir el enlace al perfil conmigo para que podamos activar la nueva página de preguntas para probar.

Comment: Gran trabajo, Pikoh. ¿Qué tal _formular_ en lugar de _hacer_ una pregunta?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' te refieres al titulo? Si,me parece mas adecuado. Puedes hacer la sugerencia si quieres en traducir.win, o lo modificaré yo mañana si no.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ya lo he modificado.

Comment: ahora mismo estaba buscándolo :D

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky i managed to get a new profile. It's [this one](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/157541/pikohpruebas)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' de todas maneras seguro que algo se puede mejorar. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida ;)

Comment: El añade hasta 5 etiquetas, generalmente los nuevos usuarios piensan que en su Instagram agregando hastags creo que debemos cambiar esa traducción

Comment: @JackNavaRow no estoy de acuerdo en eso. Ese texto es meramente descriptivo: se pueden añadir **hasta** 5 etiquetas,lo que en ningun caso implica que debas hacerlo. Por otro lado, las etiquetas son la mejor manera de categorizar las preguntas, asi que cuantas mas mejor siempre que esten realmente relacionadas con la pregunta.

Comment: Para usuarios que ya conocen el sitio sabe , pero hay otros (comunmente los nuevos) etiquetas como : frontend,javascript,react,microservicios,componentes . Y supongo que me responderás para eso son las ediciones :(

Comment: Claro @JackNavaRow, los usuarios nuevos no saben como funciona el sitio y probablemente habrá que ayudarles tanto guiándoles como con ediciones. Lo que no alcanzo a ver es en que evitaría lo que describes modificar un texto que lo único que hace es describir una funcionalidad del sitio, que el maximo de etiquetas es 5. Que texto alternativo propondrías?

Comment: `"... para describir sobre qué es tu pregunta"`. No sé uds, pero me suena un poco reforzado. Y si mejor `"... sobre qué trata tu pregunta"` ¿no?

Comment: @JheymanMejia totalmente de acuerdo. Si nadie hace la sugerencia antes, modificaré esa frase, suena mucho mas natural como dices.

Comment: sugerí (según la captura) `ocultar las ayudas de formato` por `ocultar consejos de formato` y también su contraparte `mostrar consejos de formato`

Comment: @RafaelBautistaMartinez hmm..tengo dudas con eso. Aunque la traduccion literal de "tips" es "consejos", a mi me suena mas natural en español en este contexto "ayudas" o "sugerencias"...a ver si alguien mas opina sobre este tema.

Comment: @RafaelBautistaMartinez opino igual que Pikoh, no se pero en mi región, consejo se aplica más a una opinión que se da sobre algo. Preferiría el uso de "ayudas" sobre "sugerencias", ya que esta última me parece suena a proposición. Igual, pueda en otro lugar se interprete diferente